# Application Registration Limit for Azure Tenant

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azureportal, azure-service-principal

I wanted to know if there is any limit on the number of app registrations that can be created under one Tenant or under one root-level management group in Microsoft Azure.

I am trying to make a call to this particular API

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

In order to figure out the upper limit of the number of servicePrincipals that would be returned I need to find out the maximum number of Apps that can be registered for one tenant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check resource limit for Azure here - [Azure AD service limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/directory-service-limits-restrictions)

> A maximum of 50,000 Azure AD resources can be created in a single tenant by users of the Free edition of Azure Active Directory by default. If you have at least one verified domain, the default Azure AD service quota for your organization is extended to 300,000 Azure AD resources. Azure AD service quota for organizations created by self-service sign-up remains 50,000 Azure AD resources even after you performed an internal admin takeover and the organization is converted to a managed tenant with at least one verified domain. This service limit is unrelated to the pricing tier limit of 500,000 resources on the Azure AD pricing page. To go beyond the default quota, you must contact Microsoft Support.
> A non-admin user can create no more than 250 Azure AD resources. Both active resources and deleted resources that are available to restore count toward this quota. Only deleted Azure AD resources that were deleted fewer than 30 days ago are available to restore. Deleted Azure AD resources that are no longer available to restore count toward this quota at a value of one-quarter for 30 days. If you have developers who are likely to repeatedly exceed this quota in the course of their regular duties, you can create and assign a custom role with permission to create a limitless number of app registrations.

If you're non-admin AD user limit is 250 however you can remove that limit. Please refer here. [Azure AD App registration limit for non-admin AD user](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/32334796-azure-ad-app-registration-limit-for-non-admin-ad-u#:%7E:text=There%20is%20a%20limit%20to,as%20that%20limit%20is%20reached.)